# How to use my class 'database' in another class?

Tags: python, class

I'm newer to OOP in Python, and have been trying for awhile to use my database class `database` within another class.

How can I do so?

```
class database(object):
    def connect_db(self):
        try:
            import sqlite3 as sqli
            connection = sqli.connect('pw.db')
            cur = connection.cursor()
        except:
            print("There was an error connecting to the database.")
```

I've been trying to like this, but it doesnt work:

```
 import db_helper as dbh
    class account_settings(object):
                def create_account(self):
        setting_username = input('\nUsername?\n')
        setting_password = input('\nPassword?\n')

        cur = db.connect_db()
        with cur:
            cur.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_passwords(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NULL,
                    password text UNIQUE
                )
            ''')
            try:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO my_passwords(password) VALUES(?)', (self.create_password(),) )
            except:
                print("Error occurred trying to insert password into db. Please retry")

    c = account_settings()
    c.create_account()
```

new error:

```
  File "settings.py", line 30, in <module>
    c.create_account()
  File "settings.py", line 15, in create_account
    with cur:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: I've reverted your code edit because the answerer you were following was mistaken, and the original version of the question was easier to answer.

Comment: This is very quickly turning into a chameleon question, please stop editing the question to add more to it, instead post new questions when you encounter new problems.

Comment: Its all answering the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about variable scope. `db.connect_db()` creates a cursor connection with the name `cur`, but does not do anything with it; when that method finishes, the object is destroyed. In particular, it never makes it back to the `create_account` method.

There is a simple way to solve this: *return* the object back to the method, and use it there.

```
def connect_db(self):
    ...
    cur =  connection.cursor()
    return cur

...
def create_account(self):
    cur = db.connect_db()
    with cur:
```

or even beter:

```
with db.connect_db()
```

Note that really, neither of these should be classes. Classes in Python are really only useful when you're keeping some kind of state, which isn't happening here. `connect_db` and `create_account` should just be standalone functions in their respective modules.

Comment: this is REALLY helpful, but for some reason its throwing an error  as shown above. Any ideas here? I also updated my create_account() class

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't look like you can use a cursor to introduce a with block (ie, as a context manager). What gave you the idea that you can? The docs show the use of the [connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) in that position, but not a cursor. You can call the query methods directly on the connection anyway.

Comment: I am using cur.execute() to create table, is that not using the cursor?

Comment: I don't understand that answer. You can't use a cursor object to define a with block, but you can use a connection object, and you can call execute directly on the connection. In any case, all this is a separate question from the original scope issue.